# Apache OpenNLP Part of Speech Tagger: Trained on which data set?

Tags: java, apache, part-of-speech

I am using the Apache OpenNLP Part-of-Speech Tagger for word class recognition in a collection of text. 
I am trying to evaluate the tagger for its performance and I wondered on which data it might have been trained?
The name of the models that exist for English give no hint about the used training data.

The Apache OpenNLP documentation mentions several corpora which potentially might have been used for training the POS-Tagger, too.
http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.corpora

Does anyone know how to find out on which training data the English POS-Models have been trained?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, that there are several corpora used in Opennlp.
But if you'll see the [OpenNLP Model](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) page, it's mentioned which dataset is used to train the model like below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, for the majority of taggers they mentioned. I should have mentioned that I am talking about the English models. They just say "algorithm+resource", but there must be an annotated gold data set they used which is not mentioned.